# How to make use of javascript built in arguments properly?

Tags: javascript, arguments

the number of parameters passed by each function is uncertain. Therefore I'm making use of arguments object. Now the problem is,I need to assign each value a key while pushing to an array.

arguments value is obtained like this inside for loop: arguments[i]. So how to assign each of this value to a key?

```
map: function() {

                var mappedData = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
```

> console log below, gives all values

```
                    console.debug(arguments[i]);
```

> but I need to assign each value to a key like below. How an I do that
>   please?

```
                      mappedData.push({

                        'id': arguments[0],
                        'name': arguments[1],
                        'text': arguments[2],
                        'notification': arguments[3],
                        'lastseen': arguments[4],
                        'avatar': arguments[5]
                    });
                }


            },
```

> I found the answer by myself, which is to remove the for loop inside
>   map function. That way I can access arguments[1] and assign it to the
>   key

But I don't know if there's a better answer than this, without having to call each argument with index

Comment: What do you mean by a _"assign each of this value to a key?"_?

Comment: @guest271314, take a look at my post. the arguments are saved into an array with key

Comment: Maybe you just want `i+=6` instead of `i++`? But really, I have no idea what you are trying to do. Please provide an example of how you'd want to call the function and what you expect the output to be,

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring assignment with `arguments` set to expression  following `spread` element to expand properties of `arguments` as source iterable. Return targets as properties of an object within an array.

```js
function map() {
  let [id, name, text, validation, lastseen, avatar] = [...arguments];
  let mappedData = [{id, name, text, validation, lastseen, avatar}];
  return mappedData
}
let res = map("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `[...arguments]` should be simply `arguments`. And of course, you wouldn't use the `arguments` object at all for this approach, but rather declare all these names as parameters directly.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I mean,

```
function map(){
                var mappedData = [];
                var obj = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
                {
                    console.log(i + " "+ arguments[i]);
                    if (i % 6 == 0)
                        obj.id = arguments[i];
                    if (i % 6 == 1)
                        obj.name = arguments[i];
                    if (i % 6 == 2)
                        obj.text = arguments[i];
                    if (i % 6 == 3)
                        obj.notification = arguments[i];
                    if (i % 6 == 4)
                        obj.lastseen = arguments[i];
                    if (i % 6 == 5)
                    {
                        obj.avatar =arguments[i];
                        mappedData.push(obj);
                        obj = {};
                    }

                    if(i+1 == arguments.length &&  (i % 6 != 5))
                    {
                        mappedData.push(obj);
                    }
                }
                        return mappedData;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

I fail to see the logic behind wanting to do this. If the arguments being passed are going to be used in a predetermined object, why not pass an opts parameter to the function?

```
map: function(opts){
  var mappedData = []
  mappedData.push(opts)
}
```

call it:

```
map({ ... })
```

`arguments` parameter should be used when the parameters passed to the function are not required for the function to work properly.

Comment: I don't see how you assign key for each value there?

Comment: you pass the values in the object sent to the function. `map({"id": x, "name": "foo"})` so on. or you can just create the function `map: function(id, name, text, notification, lastseen, avatar){ ... }`

Comment: I don't want to do this way. I think I still need to use arguments object. And map function should take care of assigning keys.

Comment: That is the wrong use of the `arguments` but it's up to you. Like I said, `arguments` is mostly used when the function can still work with out the arguments but if any are passed it enhances the function. You shouldn't use `arguments` if you know the parameters that are being used because if you pass 3 arguments instead of 6, the function will add 'undefined' to the properties where arguments are missing.

Comment: I know how to avoid the undefined issue here..For my function arguments is needed for some reason

Comment: is needed cause there are no parameters