# What is the syntax of this?

Tags: javascript

I believe the below code is illegal in both ES6 and ES5.

```
const app = new Vue({router}).$mount('#app')
```

Since {router} is wrong, but this example is successfully executed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/xgrjzsup/).

Can you help explain what syntax is this? What did I miss?

Comment: `{router}` is *not* wrong in ES6.

Comment: `{router}` is like `{router: router}`. Note that an Object property is not a variable, but an Object property value can be.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern creates an object having the property of `"routes"` with value of array routes.

```js
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: "Foo" },
  { path: '/bar', component: "Bar" }
]

function props(prop) {
  console.log(prop)
}

props({routes});
```

Comment: {routes} is object literal. It should be a key value pair (a:"1"). Why it only has one 'routes'?

Comment: See [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [How to make use of javascript built in arguments properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297698/how-to-make-use-of-javascript-built-in-arguments-properly/40298741#40298741), [What is this called in javascript? ({name, value}) => <span></span>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470272/what-is-this-called-in-javascript-name-value-span-span/40470289?s=4|0.0000#40470289)